# Magento 1.9.3 Display alternative image on hover on category page

Tags: image, magento, hover, categories

I want to display an alternative image on hover on category page by assigning it in Product Information -> Images. I have created an attribute hover_image with the parameters Scope-Global, Catalog Input Type-Media Image, Apply to All Product Types. Added the attribute to the set. What should I do next? Thank you

Answer (score 0):

To show the alternative hover image on category page. You need to make changes in Product Listing template in your current theme `template/catalog/product/list.phtml`.

As you have already created the media type attribute 'hover_image'. So you need to fetch `hover_image` type image like below:

```
<a href="<?php echo $_product->getProductUrl() ?>" class="hover-image" title="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'hover_image'), null, true) ?>" class="product-image"><img src="<?php echo $this->helper('catalog/image')->init($_product, 'hover_image')->resize(135); ?>" width="135" height="135" alt="<?php echo $this->stripTags($this->getImageLabel($_product, 'hover_image'), null, true) ?>" /></a>
```

Now you need to use javascript to apply hover effect on product images to hide the original image and show hover image.